# Looking for a jQuery plugin to create a sliding box effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for jQuery plug-in just like the vertical sliding box effect on the bottom of NVIDIA's homepage.

http://www.nvidia.com/page/home.html

Does anyone know any pluging like this? Thank you

Comment: This kind of questions are off-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called an accordion. jQuery UI has support for this -

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: And here for on hover: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#hoverintent

Answer (score 2):

bootstrap has all these kinds of types of components.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse

You will need some sort of jquery to make mouseover activate the accordian tab rather than clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

try these links

[jQuery UI Multiple Sections Open Accordion](http://anasnakawa.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/jquery-ui-multi-open-accordion/)

[jQuery Accordion , Tutorials And Examples](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-accordion-menus-tutorials/)

[jQuery Easy Accordion Plugin](http://www.madeincima.it/download/samples/jquery/easyAccordion/)

it will help